# how to set QDialog width and height and allow automatic window placement

Tags: qt, qdialog

Is there a way to just initialize a QDialog's width and height and not change the x and y coordinates without using a ui file? I just have a simple QDialog and want to set only the width and height, and have the x and y automatically set to the center of the parent, but when I try setGeometry, the inherited geometry's x and y are 0. How does the x and y get set when the dialog is created using a ui file?

```
class MyDialog : public QDialog
{
    MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget *parent) :
        QDialog(parent)
    {
        setGeometry(geometry().x(), geometry().y(), 200, 400);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with resize instead of setGeometry, resize should work as you expected: https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#size-prop

Comment: ok, that kind of works, but the x and y are not centered based on the new width and height.

Answer (score 7):

I have better solution:

```
class MyDialog : public QDialog
{
    MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget *parent) :
        QDialog(parent)
    {
        int nWidth = 300;
        int nHeight = 400;
        if (parent != NULL)
            setGeometry(parent->x() + parent->width()/2 - nWidth/2,
                parent->y() + parent->height()/2 - nHeight/2,
                nWidth, nHeight);
        else
            resize(nWidth, nHeight);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use with [resize](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#size-prop) instead of setGeometry, it should work as you expected.

Comment: right, but the dialog now looks like it was opened and someone resized it. it's not centered as it would be if it was created using the ui gui designer

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to extend your solution to work also on systems with a second monitor (even if this is an old thread...):

```
...
if (parent != NULL)
    QPoint parentPos = parent->mapToGlobal(parent->pos());
    setGeometry(parentPos.x() + parent->width()/2 - nWidth/2,
                parentPos.y() + parent->height()/2 - nHeight/2,
                nWidth, nHeight);
else
...
```

Marcel